# Xampp Access violation at address 005AA712 in module 'xampp-control.exe'. Read of address 00000042

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Hi I'm having trouble with my xampp control panel. I notice that everytime I access a module from my php application that is fetching around 8000 data from the database xampp keeps on prompting this error. "Exception EAccessViolation in module xampp-control.exe at 001AA712. Access violation at address 005AA712 in module 'xampp-control.exe'.Read of Address 00000042."

Windows shuts it down, fortunately leaving Apache, MySQL and PHP running.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check anything with pointers or arrays that it is not out of bounds (this might be the case with an access violation)
- or a pointer is trying to access memory not belonging to it,
- or someone forgot to allocate memory (oops).
- forgetting to free memory is another problem.
- so is freeing memory on a pointer and then trying to use it.
- calling a win32 api function with bad parameters (!)
- calling a win32 api function with parameters from an older copy of the MSDN (the API's data types DO change over time, including WinMain()) (!)

Comment: Well, i have the very same problem still as of 4 years old release, as well as of latest march 2017 release - even run with admin rights xampp gui crashes accessing address 42 and so many people at forums voe about the problem. the app starts ok, but after some time just crashes. i do restart it, it works, all the services in place running, then after some time crashes again(((((
Please, fix it at last!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file location. C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe, right click > properties > Compatibility tab and select "Run this program as an administrator". This should fix the problem.